# How can I run a UWP WebApp with selenium and appium?

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, appium, winium

I have a `UWP WebApp` and I want to run it with `selenium` and `appium`. How can I run this app?

I have Cordova Ionic app and I have .exe file and appx file, but when I use winium in selenium and give the .exe file, it's open but for install the app. I want to open this app and test it. Please advise me on how can I run it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {


        DesktopOptions option = new DesktopOptions();

        option.setApplicationPath("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\FieldService-3.1.28.1.exe");
        Thread.sleep(40000);
        WiniumDriver driver = new WiniumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999"), option);
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        //For Login Emerson
        driver.findElement(By.name("Username")).sendKeys("aashish.kumar");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys("#####");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("SIGN IN")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
```